# What is the correct way to cook Jachnun on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, yemenite-temani

I am not Yemenite and bought frozen Jachnun. The package says to cook for 8 hours. Most recipes online talk about cooking it overnight.

My question is then - isn't turning raw dough into cooked dough considered cooking on shabbat??

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jachnun): "[It] is forbidden to light a fire or cook on Shabbat. Jachnun is left in a slow oven overnight."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you may not start or enhance the cooking process on Shabbat, you *are* allowed to leave a dish to cook if the cooking process started before Shabbat began.

You would put the food into a low oven or slow-cooker before the start of Shabbat and take it out the next day when you want to eat it. You may not interfere with the food until you take it out and you may neither adjust nor turn off the oven until Shabbat ends.

There are some other considerations, such as [how cooked does the food have to be when Shabbat starts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6214/641), but my main point is that you start the food cooking while you are still allowed and leave it to cook through on its own.

Comment: This answer needs to more directly deal with the the Rabbinic prohibition against shehiya

Comment: So, removing it from the oven and putting it back is a NO?